# calculate dynamic stoppingDistance in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

For control NammeshAgent and stop after reach to destination i used OnAnimatorMove(). but when it reached to destination, run animation won't stop.

I used BlendTree for control animations. so this is my code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

//  private vriables
private Animator anim;
private NavMeshAgent navAgent;
public Transform target;
private float speed;

void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    navAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}

void Update()
{
    MoveToDestination();
}

private void MoveToDestination()
{
    // Move to Target
    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) > navAgent.stoppingDistance)
    {
        speed = 1f;
        navAgent.SetDestination(target.position);
    }
    else
    {
        speed = 0;
    }

    anim.SetFloat("Speed", speed, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
}

private void OnAnimatorMove()
{
    navAgent.speed = (anim.deltaPosition / Time.deltaTime).magnitude;
}
```

NOTE: when NavmeshAgent is reached to destination, speed value in NavmeshAgent Component is greater than 1. i seen this with print below line.

```
Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position)
```

NOTE: I set stoppingDistance to 0 in NavMesh Component.

So i need calculate stoppingdistance dinamically between player and target.

Answer (score 1):

Some minor problems with your code:

- you set `speed = 0;` but I don't see speed anywhere defined, except for navAgent.speed - make sure you use the correct/intended variable!
- `Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) > navAgent.stoppingDistance` is basically `distance > 0` - replace stoppingDistance with `0.2f` or some other small value. The distance will almost never be exactly zero, therefore (almost) always > 0.

Some thoughts:

- You could set the speed of your animations to the agent speed, so the animation would "run" but not actually move if the player won't move. Also it would scale with acceleration automatically. Maybe your blendTrees would work better then, too.
- Why did you put stopping distance to 0?

Comment: I put my edit code here and Unfortunately removed speed variable.

i want my character  stop on target position and i thought should set stopping distance to 0.
problem is when NavAgent in reached to destination, speed is great than 1.

Comment: i fixed it.

Thanks.

Comment: What was the problem, after all?

Comment: For better explain i posted solution as answer.

Answer (score 0):

problem was in this part and i removed it.

```
private void OnAnimatorMove()
{
    navAgent.speed = (anim.deltaPosition / Time.deltaTime).magnitude;
}
```

and also i set stoppingDistance to none zero.